# What does this mean

Tags: c#

in this piece of code what does C mean:

```
var Connection = 
    from C in Sessions
   where (C.StartDate >= StartDate && C.StartDate < EndDate && C.User != null)
  select new {C.User.UserName, 
              DG = C.Machine.DesktopGroup.Name};
```

https://blogsprod.s3.amazonaws.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/users-connected-to-Delivery-group-for-the-day.txt.gzip

Comment: It is just a name of iterable item of `Sessions` collection. `C` is then used in `where` and `select` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `C` represents each member of the `Sessions` collection. This is `Linq` syntax; see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) for more.

If you tell us what type of class `Sessions` is we can help more.

Answer (score 1):

It's roughly equal to this:

```
foreach (var c in sessions)
{
    c.StartDate >= [....]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a LINQ expression. The "C" is a random letter or word you set at a beginning of the expression.

I think you might need to learn a bit more about **[LINQ](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq)** expressions.